# Should the "incident" or the "accidents" tag be renamed?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

We have a [incident](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/incident) (singular) tag and a [accidents](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/accidents) (plural) one.

Should we change one to have both singular/plural?

If yes, which one?

Comment: I agree with the [differences mentioned here](http://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/14074/65), and also the plural form. Though I doubt that everyone will think twice before applying the correct tag.

Comment: I've renamed [tag:incident] to [tag:incidents].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My gut feeling says that both terms should be in their **plural form**, as the tag will list questions related to accidents or incidents and not a single incident or accident.

Comment: how does it work, then? can we do it ourselves or we have to ping a mod?

Comment: @Federico Yeah, I think we need a mod to change the names of tags.